# Running a forked repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to fork the repo and run it locally. Steps I took so far are:

1. Download repo
2. Change gemname gem version in `version.rb` to `1.4.0` because version is not available
3. Uninstall and reinstall bundler to version `1.6.1`
4. Run `bundle install`
5. Get the error `Make sure that gem install gemname -v '1.4' succeeds before bundling.`
6. Run `gem install gemname -v '1.4'` and installed gem successfully
7. Run `bundle install` and I loop back to the error on step 5

I clearly have surveyor installed but yet bundler doesn't seem to recognize this. I'm a novice and very rusty on Rails.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "downloading the repo"? How are you pointing your Gemfile to the downloaded repo?

Comment: Also, can you please paste the error backtrace that shows up when you run bundle install.

Comment: I press Clone -> Download ZIP file. I didn’t know I was supposed to point my gemfile to the downloaded repo. How could I do that?

Comment: In step 2, changing `lib/surveyor/version.rb` isn't likely to have the effect you want. What is the ultimate goal here? What is requiring `1.4.1.q`?

Comment: It’s an assignment where I’m supposed to make a website with the surveyor gem to make some surveys. I’m supposed to fork that branch from the link above.

Answer (score 1):

To depend on a version of a gem in a Git repo, [tell the bundler to fetch the gem from the repo](https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/git.html).

```
gem 'surveyor', '~> 1.4', git: 'https://github.com/scwong93/surveyor/'
```

And then run `bundle` as normal. You should see...

> Using surveyor 1.4.1.q from https://github.com/scwong93/surveyor/ (at master@e253789)

Look inside your `Gemfile.lock` and see that it has indeed found the repo version 1.4.1q by pulling it from the repo's master branch.

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/scwong93/surveyor/
  revision: e25378983fd465db701610eb076179c74db98c11
  specs:
    surveyor (1.4.1.q)
      formtastic (~> 2.2.1)
      haml (>= 4.1.0.beta.1)
      mustache (~> 0.99)
      rabl (~> 0.6)
      rails (>= 3.2)
      sass
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
```

Comment: I've added the first line of code (gem surveyor) into my Gemfile and ran bundle install but ran into the same error: NoMethodError: undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass Did you mean?  inspect An error occurred while installing surveyor (1.4.1.q), and Bundler cannot continue.

Comment: @SimonWong You've never mentioned this error. Something else is wrong.